# no suitable conversion function from "std::wstring" to "LPWSTR" exists in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

By using the below code, I am getting the path "C:\ProgramFiles"

And then appending "\Test\myupdate.exe" to it.

After that I am storing this path in the "pwszTaskTrigger" structure variable like as below:

```
mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath;
```

But, When storing I am getting a warning message ("no suitable conversion function from "std::wstring" to "LPWSTR" exists"):

Below is the complete Code:

```
MCTASKINFO mcTskInfo = { 0 };
WCHAR szCommonFiles[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
lRet = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, NULL, 0, szCommonFiles);
std::wstring strexepath = L"";
    strexepath.append(szCommonFiles);  //szCommonFiles gives the path "C:\\ProgramFiles"
    strexepath.append(ADD_MCUPDTPATH);
    mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath;

#define ADD_MCUPDTPATH          L"\\Test\\myupdate.exe"


struct MCTASKINFO
{

LPWSTR pwszTaskTrigger; 

};
```

Here I should not change the structure variable pwszTaskTrigger from LPWSTR to LPCWSTR. Because this file is the include file.

How can I fix this issue without changing LPWSTR to LPCWSTR?

Comment: You can solve the error easily by getting a pointer to the first element of the string (as in `&strexepath[0]`). *But* that could lead to other errors if the object `strexepath` ends its life and gets destructed before the pointer does.

Comment: Why not using `mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath.c_str();`?

Comment: @Gupta that's `const wchar_t *`.

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean? In C++11, `data()` and `c_str()` are the same, no?

Comment: @Gupta yes, and both of them return `const`... I just fixed my answer thanks to sklott.

Comment: @Gupta In C++17, `data()` has an overload that returns a non-const pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = &strexepath[0];
```

Or, in C++17, be more descriptive and use `data`:

```
mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath.data();
```

But make extra sure that nothing writes more than the length of the string through that pointer, nor uses it after `strexepath`'s lifetime has ended.

Comment: Non-const `data()` is available only since C++17, and this question has C++11 tag.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, As you mentioned I changed like: mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath.data();

Comment: But it is showing the error message: a value of type "const wchar_t*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPWSTR"

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder that's because you are using C++11, which sklott pointed out to me. `data` has been updated since then, but you're restricted to using `&strexepath[0]` which has the same effect.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin, mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = &strexepath[0]; is working.

Comment: mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = (LPWSTR)strupdatepath.c_str();  --- This way also it is working. Can I use this way?

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder I'd say it is way uglier since you have to cast `const` away.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger=const_cast<wchar_t*>(strexepath.c_str());
```

You can also use a C-style cast instead of const_cast. Then the line would look like:

```
mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = (LPWSTR)strupdatepath.c_str();
```

Comment: Can I use this way? mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = (LPWSTR)strupdatepath.c_str();  --- It is also working.

Comment: I added the possibility of using a C-style cast to my answer.

Comment: You don't need the cast: `mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = &strexepath[0];`, or `mcTskInfo.pwszTaskTrigger = strexepath.data();` in C++17.